# round to the nearest even number with array of numbers

Tags: octave

My function and rounding to nearest even number

```
function y = rndeven(x)
    if x<=1
      y=2;
    else  
      y = 2*floor(x);
    end

endfunction
```

When I run it I get:

```
cc=[0:3]'
both=[cc,rndeven(cc)]

0                     0
1                     2
2                     4
3                     6
```

**What I'm trying to get as the Result:**

```
0                     2
1                     2
2                     2
3                     4
```

Comment: Why is `0` not an even number? Also, from the tag info for both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave], "Don’t use both the [matlab] and [octave] tags, unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two." Will your input have negative integers? If so, which direction do you want to round them?

Comment: 3 is closer to 4 than to 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulo 2 to find whether a number is even. If it isn't this will return 1, so just add 1 to this number to find the nearest (larger) even number:

```
function y = rndeven(x)
    x = floor(x);
    x(x <= 1) = 2;
    y = mod(x,2)+x;
end
```

This works for any array, order of elements does not matter.

Answer (score -1):

You could also check if it is dividable by 2 if you don't want to use the mod function. The pseudo code would be something like this:

while(x % 2 != 0) x = x + 1

return x

Comment: How is `x % 2` not using the `mod` function? In the sence that it uses the modulo operator (which does not exist in Matlab)?